# I need more advice on this data addition issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, visual-basic

I have a test program consisting of a textbox (textbox1), a button (save), and a connection to a database and a table called TestDatabase.mdf and TestTable (respectively). I am trying to save the text which I will input into the database through 'textbox1'....

I have done this much so far:

```
Dim mytextboxvalue As String
    mytextboxvalue = TextBox1.Text
    sqCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestTable" & "(FirstColumn,   SecondColumn)" & "(mytextboxvalue,mytextboxvalue)"
```

And I am getting this run-time error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'mytextboxvalue'.
```

So my question is that what is the correct syntax?

Comment: Where is TextBox1.Text defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sqCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestTable" & "(FirstColumn,   SecondColumn) values" & "('mytextboxvalue','mytextboxvalue')"
```

And remember to use `'` if they are string!

Comment: It still says Incorrect syntax near 'mytextboxvalue'....what to do please help

Comment: what's the data type of `FirstColumn`?

Comment: VarChar (MAX) it is why?

Comment: answer please p

Comment: It's beath to put an @symbol before the name of the person you are replying to. This will notify them. e.g @ Username

Comment: check new edit!!

Comment: @Death it is inputing mytextboxvalue and not the actual value instead

Comment: mark it as answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
sqCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestTable (FirstColumn, SecondColumn) values ('" & mytextboxvalue & "','" & mytextboxvalue & "')"
```

... `mytextboxvalue` is a variable whose text you want to add into your `INSERT INTO` string.

Note that if anyone but yourself enters text into that textbox, **you should not do it this way!!** Have a look at the ["Bobby Tables" issue](http://bobby-tables.com/) for more details about avoiding SQL injections.

Comment: @Lambe: If my information is helpful, you should upvote the answer (click the upward arrow)...